# What is this piece of c++ code doing?

Tags: c++, seqan

I don't know how and why this piece of code works:

```
// postorder dfs
Iterator< Index<String<char> >, TopDown<ParentLink<Postorder> > >::Type
     myIterator(myIndex);
while (goDown(myIterator));
for (; !atEnd(myIterator); goNext(myIterator)) 
// do something with myIterator ( Traverse Through (Suffix)-tree )
```

It's an example from [seqan](http://www.seqan.de/dddoc/html/Page_Indices.html) and the interface is described here: [API](http://www.seqan.de/dddoc/html/Spec_TopDownHistory%20Iterator.html)

1. How can the while affect the for-loop?
2. Why isn't the for loop initialized?

Comment: There's no metaprogramming involved here. Not all uses of templates are metaprogramming.

Comment: I think the worst thing to come out of template metaprogramming is that now lots of people seem to think that any code with templates is an example of metaprogramming.

Comment: Type `Iterator< Index<String<char> >, TopDown<ParentLink<Postorder> > >::Type` may well be calculated using a metaprogram

Comment: -1 for not choosing an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've run into the fun parts of C++ - using language constructs in syntactically valid but difficult-for-human-parsing techniques.

```
while (goDown(myIterator));
```

This will "goDown(myIterator)" until it returns false.  Then it will continue onto the for loop.  It's looping over nothing - but that's okay, because the function goDown is doing work.

```
for (; !atEnd(myIterator); goNext(myIterator))
```

This doesn't initialize anything, but tests that it's not atEnd(myIterator) - while it's not, it will goNext(myIterator).  It could also be written as a while loop to make it slghtly easier to understand:

```
while(!atEnd(myIterator)) 
{
    goNext(myIterator));
}
```

So the code will:

1. Go down until goDown() returns false - this means goDown is modifying myIterator each time
2. goNext() until it is atEnd()

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, `goDown` and `goNext` are taking their argument by reference and altering it. So the answer to your two questions is, 1. the `while` calls `goDown` a number of times, altering `myIterator` as it goes, and this is the indirect influence you're talking about, since 2. the `for` starts with `myIterator` exactly as the `while` left it -- so of course it doesn't reassign it, that would undo all the while's work!